# combining several UI elements in one view class

Tags: android, textview

I would like to define my own view class that consists of several Textviews, ImageViews, ProgressViews into one DisplayClass with these as elements.

The idea behind this is that one can reuse the DisplayClass several times in XML and easily access/update the different DisplayClass instances.

In XML it would look like one customized widget that is used several times, like here...

```
    <myDisplayClass
                android:id="@+id/id1"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:leftText ="x1..."
                android:midText = "y1.."
                android:topText = "z1.."
                ...and other fields />

  <myDisplayClass
                android:id="@+id/id2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:leftText ="x2..."
                android:midText = "y2.."
                android:topText = "z2.."
                ...and other fields />

 <myDisplayClass
                android:id="@+id/id3"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:leftText ="x3..."
                android:midText = "y3.."
                android:topText = "z3.."
                ...and other fields />

<myDisplayClass
                android:id="@+id/id_n"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:leftText ="x.n.."
                android:midText = "y.n."
                android:topText = "z.n."
                ...and other fields />
```

While it is based on one layout display_class.xml which defines the layout only once.

Many thanks for any ideas, hints or if available examples/tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reuse a common xml code:

you can define it in separate layout say commonlayout.xml which will have Linear/Relative layout etc as parent with all the views you want in there.

In any xml code you want to use that layout , you can just use

`<include layout="@layout/commonlayout" />`

PS : I don't see  your need to define `myDisplayClass` in the question you have given, if you just want to use the default EditText/TextViews/Widgets etc.. or maybe you can explain it out if the answer mentioned wasn't you were looking for..

**EDIT :** 
after prob specified in comments:

```
View layout1 = findViewById(R.id.layout1); 
TextView tv = (TextView)layout1.findViewById(R.id.commonTextView);
```

similarly for another textview in second layout

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView)layout2.findViewById(R.id.commonTextView);
```

Comment: lets say in this include there are 3 TextViews. So when writing  <include android:id="@+id/commonlayout1" layout="@layout/common_layout_stuff" />  followed by another<include android:id="@+id/commonlayout1" layout="@layout/common_layout_stuff" /> one cannot access the 3 TextViews of the first or the second one, since the underying TextViews have the same ids. Only the top elements have different ids, eg commonlayout1 and 2 - this means that one cannot use this unfortunately when having to access the content - or did I miss something here?

Comment: After EDIT - thanks, with this one can access the fields. All I need now is a comfortable way to access them comfortably without having to hardcode the ids from the XML in the code. Would be nice to say sth like: "for tmp_layout in layout_x do tv = tmp_layout...." By the way I found the "general" solution too. It is much more complicated but very flexible. Create a subclass of View and implement all the methods esp the drawing all elements step by step on canvas  is fun :-)